# What are the requirements for a PPL to upgrade from SEL to MEL?

Tags: faa-regulations, multi-engine

Reading the requirements for MEL it is confusing which things must be done in a multi-engine, and which things carry over from SEL. If I already have SEL do I need to do a cross country in a multi-engine? Assuming I can meet the PTS for MEL, what other requirements are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appropriate paragraph of Part 61 of CFR 14 is 61.63 (emphasis mine, the '*unless*' part does not apply in your case):

> (c) **Additional aircraft class rating**. A person who applies for an
>   additional class rating on a pilot certificate:
>
> (1) Must have a logbook or training record endorsement from an
>   authorized instructor attesting that the person was found competent in
>   the appropriate aeronautical knowledge areas and proficient in the
>   appropriate areas of  operation.
>
> (2) Must pass the practical test.
>
> (3) **Need not meet the specified training time requirements
>   prescribed by  this part that apply to the pilot certificate for the
>   aircraft class rating sought;** unless, the person only holds a
>   lighter-than-air category rating with a balloon class rating and is
>   seeking an airship class rating, then that person must receive the
>   specified training time requirements and  possess the appropriate
>   aeronautical experience.
>
> (4) Need not take an additional knowledge test, provided the applicant
>   holds an airplane, rotorcraft, powered-lift, weight-shift-control
>   aircraft, powered parachute, or airship rating at that pilot
>   certificate level.

So, to answer your question, no, you do not need a cross-country, you do not need any solo time in a multiengine airplane, either. All you need is a sign off from your instructor.